# Android app crashes when defining and setting element properties

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My app is crashing. What am I doing wrong?

I am using an AsyncTask in a class fetchsSchools.

```
public class fetchSchools extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>>{     
@Override
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    ArrayList<School> schools = new ArrayList<School>();
    ArrayList<String> schoolNames = new ArrayList<String>();
     ... code omitted for conciseness...

   return schoolNames;   
}
```

In this class I  have an onPost Execute, my code gets to this, if I remark out the cls2 lines my app runs:

```
public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> schoolNames) {
MainActivity cls2=new MainActivity();
cls2.updateSpinner(schoolNames);
cls2.switchScreens();
}
```

The above fires off these two outines back in MainActivity which crash the app:

```
public void updateSpinner(ArrayList<String> schoolNames) {     
Spinner schoolSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.school_spinner);
schoolSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, schoolNames));
}

public void switchScreens() {    
ProgressBar progressBar1 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);   
progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);  
TextView loading_label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.loading_label);     
loading_label.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Eclipse isn't showing any coding errors. Am I creating and acting on these variables correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Though you have not given code for MainActivity and logcat. Seeing your code looks like MainActivity extends Activity. If so you cannot call

```
MainActivity cls2=new MainActivity();
```

MainActivity has to be initialized by `android framework` with appropriate context. Calling constructor yourself will not call any lifecycle methods of the Activity.

So all subsequent calls that use Context will fail, especially `findViewByid`

You need to do `startActivity` instead of what you are doing.

Edit:
Create a constructor in Asynctask pass MainActivity when instantiating and assign like below and remove `new MainActivity` line

```
public class fetchSchools extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>>{  
       MainActivity cls2;
       fetchSchools(MainActivity activity){
         cls2 = activity;
      }   
@Override
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    ArrayList<School> schools = new ArrayList<School>();
    ArrayList<String> schoolNames = new ArrayList<String>();
     ... code omitted for conciseness...

   return schoolNames;   
}

public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> schoolNames) {
cls2.updateSpinner(schoolNames);
cls2.switchScreens();
}
```

}

In MainActivity, you call

```
new fetchSchools(mMainActivity).execute(param);
```

Comment: (and yes MainActivity does extend Activity).
Can you elaborate on how I should code startActivity?

Comment: @rihallix You should explain the relationship between `MainActivity` and the `AsyncTask`. Maybe you don't need to call `startActivity()` if your `MainActivity` is already running...

Comment: When my asyncTask completes (onPostExecute) I want to flip a bunch of elements from visibility GONE to VISIBLE and vice versa, like this. I tried doing this in the fetchSchools class but couldn't reference the elements (was told via another StackOverflower to create a function back in MainActivity to achieve this). This is the code I've got back in the MainActivity function:

`ProgressBar progressBar1 = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);   
 progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);`
So should do the element updates in the new class or in MainActivity calling it via startActivity?

Comment: How do I pass MyTask the additional parameter `ArrayList<String> schoolNames` ?
How does this new private class still get called by onPostExecute?

Comment: @nan So I get these errors in Eclipse against the private class line:  
_Multiple markers at this line  
- The type fetchSchools.MyTask must implement the inherited abstract method  
 AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<String>>.doInBackground(Void...)
 - The type fetchSchools.MyTask is never used locally_

Again I really need to pass the ArrayList<String> schoolNames to this function.

Comment: Apologies, I'm confused.    
  What specifically goes in Main Activity?
  What specifically goes into my class fetchSchools, and does it go inside my existing `public class fetchSchools extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>>` ?
Apologies if I haven't communicated this clearly enough.

Comment: I have edited the code. add the code where you are calling execute of fetchschools and also the class name, if the edit does not work

Answer (score 0):

If this is a seperate class from that your main activity, then you're trying to findViewById from where? You probably get NullPointerException on very first line of onPostExecute which is this one:

```
cls2.updateSpinner(schoolNames);
```

Because you try to find a view in this method. But you do not have any parent view which contains the view that you seek to find.

So i would suggest you to move this fetchSchools class as a private inner class of your mainActivity. so you'll be able to find those views globally and set them however you want.